# Unable to connect to vncserver on google cloud VM Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, vnc, cloud, google

Good evening all,

I have been trying to connect to my google cloud VM instance Ubuntu 17.04 via VNC viewer for a good few hours and have tried everything.

i can see the port is open to connections on 5901

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5901/tcp open   vnc-1
```

I also checked

```
nc 35.2**.55.*** 5901
```

and get

```
RFB 003.008
```

Then when i try to connect with VNCViewer it says the connection closed unexpectedly.

What am I doing wrong here. Do i need to configure vncserver on my VM with SSH key or the viewer with SSH key.

What am I missing here. Its driving me crazy.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Check if your External IP is fixed, in the network settings of your VM

Comment: Do you get an internal IP in Google cloud now?